# A discussion related to a convexity of infimal convolution

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I reading a book which is convex optimization (Stephen Boyd). I have a question in the section "Operations that preserve convexity". Particularly, I said that

> If $f$ is convex in (x,y), and $C$ is a convex nonempty set, then the function
> $$g(x) = \inf_{y \in C} f(x,y)$$
> is convex in $x$, provided $g(x) > -\infty$ for all $x$.

After reading that , I tried to solve an exercises in a book

> The infimal convolution of two functions $f$ and $g$ on $\mathbf{R}^n$ is defined as
> $$
> h(x)=\inf _y(f(y)+g(x-y))
> $$
> Prove that if $f, g$ are convex, then $h$ is convex.

Although I know that there are many proofs of the convexity of the infimal convolution available on the internet, I am still posting this topic to discuss it more clearly because they approach it by using other theorems.

Here is my attempt:

We have $t(x, y) = f(y) + g(x - y)$, which is convex because both $f$ and $g$ are convex. Now, let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and I need to prove that $h(x) > -\infty$. However, I am unsure about how to proceed with this. I am concerned that the book might have omitted the assumption that $f$ and $g$ are **PROPER** convex functions. Have I made any mistakes?

Furthermore, if I suppose that $f$, $g$ should be PROPER, convex. Then, can I continue my proof in the following way:

Fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $f(y) + g(x-y) > -\infty$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Then $h(x) > -\infty$ forall $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Even if $f$ and $g$ are proper, the infimal convolution might be $-\infty$ everywhere: Consider $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = -x$.

Comment: Do you know how to modify that exercise ?

Comment: You need an affine function $a$ with $f \ge a$ and $g \ge a$.

Comment: suppose that h(x) = -\infty. I think that it still satisfies the convexity formula right?

Comment: Furthermore, f(y) +g(y-x) = y -(y-x) = x then h(x) = x. It is still convex

Comment: @Pipnap: It is $f(y) + g(x-y) = 2 y - x$. And if you accept that your functions take values in $[-\infty,\infty]$, the infimal convolution is always convex.